# Angular 2 Custom Validator with Observable Parameter

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have this custom validator:

```
export const mealTypesValidator = (mealSelected: boolean) => {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        var mealTypes = control.value;
        if (mealTypes) {
            if (mealTypes.length < 1 && mealSelected) {
                return {
                    mealTypesValid: { valid: false }
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
};
```

If I use it like this it works:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [[], mealTypesValidator(true)],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}
```

The catch is, mealSelected is a property on my component - that changes when the user selects and deselects a meal.

How I call the validator above is using static true which can never change.

How can I get the validator to work when I use the component.mealSelected value as the parameter eg:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [[], mealTypesValidator(this.mealSelected)],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}
```

Because if i do it as above, it evaluates `this.mealSelected` instantly which is false at the time - and then when the user selects a meal, it doesn't then go ahead and pass true into the custom validator.

Comment: Another possibility is to define  a validator to the whole formGroup, rather than for  the  individual mealTypes control.  A downside: where to put the error message or flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to move the validator inside my component and use `this.mealSelected` to check against. Then I had an issue with the validator not being triggered when a meal was selected/deselected and I used `this.findForm.controls['mealTypes'].updateValueAndValidity();` to trigger the validation.

Code (can probably be refactored to remove the parameter from the custom validator):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [[], this.mealTypesValidator(true)],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}

mealTypesValidator = (mealSelected: boolean) => {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        var mealTypes = control.value;
        if (mealTypes) {
            if (mealTypes.length < 1 && this.mealSelected) {
                return {
                    mealTypesValid: { valid: false }
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
};
```

**However** It would still be nice to be able to have a seperate validation module to centralise validation, so if anyone knows how to have a changing parameter value such as a component field as a parameter to a custom validator - like I initially asked, then I'd appreciate an answer that goes with that technique.